# source command is not working inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am literally new to the scripting language.

I have to run `source ~/.custom_rc` command from within a shell script. When I run the shell script, It doesn't show any error. It run just fine.

Here is my `install.sh` file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Some Comments
#
# End of Comments

echo ""
.
.
.
.
.
.
source ~/.custom_rc

echo "End Of Script..."
```

I am executing the script from curl using `sh -c` like,

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://some.link/to/install.sh)"
```

Why the command isn't running inside the script? How am I supposed to make them run inside shell scripting?

##### EDIT #1:

I am using alias commands inside the `.custom_rc` file.

Once the execution completed, I am unable to use the alias commands.

But, when I manually run `source ~/.custom_rc`, alias commands works fine.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't run? What is the expected result from running it?

Comment: _and_, given that you are pulling install.sh from a remote server, where is `.custom_rc`? It is in your home directory, I would assume, right?

Comment: @eftshift0 I am using alias commands inside the `.custom_rc` file. Once the execution completed, I am unable to use the alias commands. But, when I manually run `source ~/.custom_rc`, alias commands works fine.

Comment: As an aside, you've declared the script as a `bash` script but you're running it with `sh`. That's potentially a problem.

Comment: @eftshift0  `.custom_rc' file is created within the shell script and moved to the home directory within the shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.... I see what's going on. If you would like to be able to use the aliases defined in `.custom_rc` *after* `sh` is done executing, then that won't work because the aliases are getting set in the `sh` session. They will die along with it when `sh` is finished. In other words, you should be able to use the aliases since running `source` up until the last line of `install.sh`.

You need help from yet another script that takes care of this:

wrapper.sh:

```
curl https://some.link/to/install.sh # download the script so you can source it
. install.sh # source it
```

(or something like that)

Then, you should be able to run `. wrapper.sh` and it should work (notice how you also source this one).

### Update

About the comment about it not working:

```
$ cat script1.sh 
alias alias1="echo hola"

. script2.sh

$ cat script2.sh 
alias alias2="echo adios"

$ ./script1.sh 
$ alias1
bash: alias1: command not found
$ alias2
bash: alias2: command not found
$ . script1.sh 
$ alias1
hola
$ alias2
adios
```

Comment: I just wanted to run a single command for the entire process which is already a curl command. Is there any option?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have also tried running the script locally after saving the remote file locally, It still doesn't source my file.

Comment: How do you run it? with `./script.sh`? That won't work. It has to be sourced.

Comment: You might also want to mention that `source` is a bash thing, not portable. If `sh` isn't `bash` on the OP's system, `source foo.sh` won't work and they should use `. foo.sh`. I know you've written it that way, but I'm thinking it might be worth mentioning it explicitly as this might also be part of the problem.

Comment: Actually, those are tiny details that I am not aware of. Thanks for bringing it up, @terdon